# Make kubectl work in gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab-ci, kubectl

I am searching for a way to use kubectl in gitlab.

So far I have the following script:

```
deploy_to_dev:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:dind
  environment:
    name: dev
  script:
    - mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
    - echo $KUBE_CONFIG | base64 -d > $HOME/.kube/config
    - kubectl config view
  only:
    - develop
```

But it says that gitlab does not know kubectl. So can you point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use image `google/cloud-sdk` which has a preinstalled installation of gcloud and kubectl.

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  services:
  - docker:dind
  script:
  # Make gcloud available
  - source /root/.bashrc
```

Comment: There are also some images with just kubectl installed like
    bitnami/kubectl
    rancher/kubectl
    ibmcom/kubectl
    ...

Answer (score 21):

You are using `docker:dind`image which does not have the kubectl binary, you should bring your own image with the binary or download it in the process

```
deploy_to_dev:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine:3.7
  environment:
    name: dev
  script:
    - apk update  && apk add --no-cache curl
    - curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
    - chmod +x ./kubectl && mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
    - mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
    - echo -n $KUBE_CONFIG | base64 -d > $HOME/.kube/config
    - kubectl config view
  only:
    - develop
```

Comment: Now i got this ERROR: Job failed: image pull failed: Back-off pulling image "alpine:3" and my question is what kind of image is this?

Comment: That's my bad is alpine:3.7 or any valid tag, alpine is a small docker linux image(5mb) https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/

Comment: now this: $ curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
/bin/sh: eval: line 54: curl: not found
/bin/sh: eval: line 54: curl: not found

Comment: Updated the script, What I was trying to give you is a sense of how you could make it, my suggestions is that you create your own image with kubectl in there. but the updated script should work now

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I will create a Image with curl and kubectl in it.

Comment: how about this image `https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kubectl/` looks a fit, more than to install kubectl each time in image `alpine`